# why is my variable is undefined outside of a constructor on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the classList of my icon to a random value from a array. But when I run this code it says "this.classList" is undefined. Why is this happening?

Heres my full file, I have inserted the fontawsome file on my main html file.

```js
//Heres the Dice.js file:

import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Dice.css";

class Dice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { class: [] };
    var classList = [
      "fas fa-dice-one dice",
      "fas fa-dice-two dice",
      "fas fa-dice-three dice",
      "fas fa-dice-four dice"
    ];
    let numPicker = this.numPicker.bind(this);
  }
  numPicker(e) {
    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.classList.length);
    
    //Why is this.classList is Undefined

    let classPicker = this.classList[randNum];
    this.state.class.push(classPicker);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.numPicker()}
        <i className={this.state.class}></i>
        <button onClick={this.diceChanger()}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dice;






//Heres the Default App.js file: 

import React from "react";
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import "./App.css";
import Dice from "./Dice";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dice />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
.dice {
  font-size: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I run this, and it says **this.classList** is undefined. What should I do Now?

Comment: `this.classList = [`...?

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor change `var classList = [...]` to `this.classList = [...]` which is what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to add the array to the function? I recommend reading/following some more guides. You should for example use setState instead of what you're trying to do.

Code Example:

```
class Dice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentClass: [] };
  }

  numPicker(e) {
    const classList = [
      "fas fa-dice-one dice",
      "fas fa-dice-two dice",
      "fas fa-dice-three dice",
      "fas fa-dice-four dice"
    ];
    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length);
    const currentClass = this.classList[randNum];
    this.setState({ currentClass });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.numPicker()}
        <i className={this.state.currentClass}></i>
        <button onClick={this.diceChanger()}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dice;
```